# Which function can I use to find AVERAGE of a set of numbers in SQL?

Tags: sql, average

I am very new to SQL and I am still trying to understand it. I was trying to find the average of a set of numbers but I don't know which function to use. In the SELECT statement , I wrote SELECT AVG as was written in the example I was working on and it returned error message 'Table Not Found'.

Comment: Please add the exact code you ran and identify your DB (MySQL, SQL Server, ...).  Some of them want us to use `FROM DUAL` when no tables are required.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message you gave, I think  you have misunderstood how the avg keyword works.

```
Select avg(<the value you want to check the average of>)
FROM <table name here>;
```

**Example**

```
SELECT AVG(Price)
FROM Products;
```

**Please note**

As the comments on your threat states, please provide us with what SQL database you are using. Are you using PostgresSQL, mysql etc. Different SQL databases have different features and I can be helpful for us to know what you are using

Also, if you can provide us with the information on the table (which fields the table contains) we can provide you with a more specific SQL query

Here is a great tutorial that might help you further!

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Hope this helps